# Background-size: cover causing background image to resize on touch in mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue where I'm setting the background-image of a page in mobile to a new image designed for mobile. The image is set to `background-size: cover`, and is working fine in everything except for mobile Chrome. When scrolling in mobile Chrome, the image is resizing slightly. The design also has an absolute footer. You can see it in action here:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  }

.image {
  display: block;
  background: url(http://drawingimage.com/files/1/Shrek-Donkey-Beautiful-Image-Drawing.png) no-repeat center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -69px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    <p> Footer info </p>
    <p> More footer info</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If no answer here helps, you might want to report this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If it covers the background then it leaves room for scrolling. Perhaps constrain the container. Or consider using any kind of media query to trap the problem on mobile sizes. Switching it to contain on mobile only. or removing the overflow scroll on mobile.

Comment: Switching to contain and removing overflow scroll have both failed me unfortunately.

Comment: I feel like your question is missing pieces... Do you require the image to stay full width? This just looks like an odd approach to the solution.
You can use jQuery to find the height of the absolutely positioned footer elements since they aren't part of the box model. And then set the height of the image container to be the difference of full screen minus the footer sections. Then constrict it to the container and hide the overflow just for safe measures. There's a couple different ways to go about it. You could always have a different image for mobile also that wasn't oddly shapped.